# Page is not showing fit into the screen

Tags: css

Can anyone please help me, i created a site where i put the following size to the page.

Here is the HTML ..

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="container" >
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS

```
html {
    background:#333;
}

body {
    width:1280px;
    background:#fff;
    margin:0px auto;
}


#container {
    width:1100px;
    background:#fff;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

the problem is that I am having on the left hand side the required accurate required margin but on the right hand side it shows the extra margin space please tell me how can i fix this and why is this happened?

Comment: You are giving the body and the #container a fixed width, is that what you want?

Comment: I want to give container width 1100px and the body width is 1280.

Comment: My overall page size is width:1280px  and height:2300px

Answer (score 0):

You can use positioning in CSS to determine where the content is viewed on the page.

You can add `left:`, `right:`, `top:`, or `bottom:` to determine exactly where you want your content to sit on your page.

Centering the content is also a possibility by adding `#container {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}` to center your container.

Centering the content vertically is also possible by adding `vertical-align:center` to your CSS class (or id).

Hope this helped!